# Kubernetes Ingress backend path with postfix

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I can not understand how to achieve such a result as in nginx configuration:

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://xyz:9000/api_server/;
}
```

but with ingress. If I understand correctly [nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#app-root) is a redirection, but not proxying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each ingress rule works already as a `proxy_pass` directive. So you can use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation in your case:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api_server/$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service-xyz
            port:
              number: 9000
```